# Create different subsets, plot them and store the plots

Tags: r, dataframe, ggpubr

I have a series of large dataframes which look like these:

```
Year   Variable   Class
1999   0.4504     a
1999   0.4244     a
1999   0.8980     b
1999   0.8901     b
2000   0.2552     a
2000   0.6504     a
2000   0.7830     b
2000   0.2030     b
...    ...        ...
...    ...        ...
2018   0.6520     a
2018   0.1403     a
2018   0.4502     b
2018   0.1240     b
```

With 15 different classes and a minimum of 500 observations for each year and class. What I want to do is create a subset for each year and class (so 20 years * 15 classes = 300 subsets) and make a Q-Q plot to look at their distribution, to see how much they differ from normality.

Problem is, even if I can create the subsets with a loop, I don't know how to store the plots to look at them afterwards.

The idea is something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggpubr)

dataframe_list <- list.files(path="B:/Data/", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)
years <- c(1999:2018)

for (i in 1:13){
  db <- fread(dataframe_list[i])
  for (j in 1:length(years)){
    db_year <- subset(db, db$Year==years[j])
    class <- levels(as.factor(db_year$Class))
    for (k in 1:length(class)){
      db_year_class <- subset(db_year, db_year$Class==class[k])
    } 
  }
}
```

Make the plot in the third loop using:

```
ggqqplot(db_year_class$Variable)
```

and store it in some way until I have all of them at the end of the loop. Since they are at least 300 for every dataframe on the list, store the plots in one file for each dataframe would be great.

**Edit** Ok, that's how I adapted it:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggpubr)

dataframe_list <- list.files(path="B:/Data/", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)
df <- c(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M)
years <- c(1999:2018)
plot_list <- list()

for (i in 1:13){
  db <- fread(dataframe_list[i])
  for (j in 1:length(years)){
    db_year <- subset(db, db$Year==years[j])
    class <- levels(as.factor(db_year$Class))
    for (k in 1:length(class)){
      db_year_class <- subset(db_year, db_year$Class==class[k])
      plot_list[[k]] <- ggqqplot(db_year_class$Variable)+ggtitle(paste0("Code_0_", df[i], "_", years[j], "_", class[k]))
      outfiles <- paste0("B:/Results/Plot/Code_0_", df[i], "_", years[j], ".pdf")
      pdf(file=outfiles, onefile = TRUE)
      for(z in seq_along(list)) {
        print(plot_list[[z]])
      }
      dev.off()
    } 
  }
}
```

The result is a pdf for each year, which isn't so handy but otherwise using a list object wouldn't work: the list would have been overwritten at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a prototype for you to use - I just did one loop across `cyl` values in the `mtcars` dataset, but you can extend this to your use case:

```
library(ggplot2)
#container list to hold ggplots
l <- list()

#unique cylinder groups
cyl_groups <- sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))

#iterate through each cylinder group, plotting mpg vs disp
for(j in seq_along(cyl_groups)){
  l[[j]] <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == cyl_groups[[j]], ], aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0("Cylinders = ", cyl_groups[j]))
}

#save into one PDF
pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  print(l[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

This gives you on PDF with a page for each plot.